# How to set mail message as seen using S22.imap in C#

Tags: c#, imap

I used S22.imap package to read all unread emails like below, then I want to mark the unseen mail as seen after reading it, how can I do this please.

```
string host = "host";
            int port = port;
            string username = "username";
            string password = "psw";
            using (ImapClient client = new ImapClient(host, port, username, password, AuthMethod.Login, true))
            {
                IEnumerable<uint> uids = client.Search(SearchCondition.Unseen());
                // Download mail messages from the default mailbox.
                IEnumerable<MailMessage> messages = client.GetMessages(uids, FetchOptions.Normal);
                foreach (var item in messages)
                {
                    string from = item.From.ToString();
                    string body = item.Body.ToString();
                    string subject = item.Subject.ToString();
                    Console.WriteLine(from + "-" + body + "-" + subject);
                }
                
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
MessageFlag[] flags = new[] { MessageFlag.Seen };
client.SetMessageFlags(id, null, flags);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: See "[answer]" and [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.

Comment: Worked 100%. Tks